# Creating an individual event listener for each new element appended

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a button, class name "originalButton".
When I click original button it needs to append a new button to the page.
How do I set an event listener for each button, that will give a different output based on the button's position.

For example if I click originalButton 100 times it would have appended 100 new butons.
If I click new button number 1 it will console.log "I am button 1".
Likewise if I clicked new button number 100 it must console.log "I am button 100"

Here is the code I've attempted, but I just can't seem to get it to work.
I don't need to know how to do this without the help of any js frameworks.
Any help will be highly appreciated:

```
const mainButton = document.querySelector('.mainButton');
let i = 1;

mainButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
const newButton = document.createElement('button');
    document.body.append(newButton);
    newButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log(`I am button ${i}`);
        i= i+1
    })
    
})
```

Comment: You only have a single variable `i` that is used by all buttons.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a single callback function (`onButtonClick`)
2. While creating the buttons, save the `i` somewere (eg: dataset)
3. In the callback, get the ID and log to console

```js
const mainButton = document.querySelector('.mainButton');
let i = 1;

mainButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const newButton = document.createElement('button');
    newButton.onclick = onButtonClick;
    newButton.dataset.id = i;
    newButton.innerHTML = '#' + i;
    i++;
    document.body.append(newButton);    
});

const onButtonClick = () => {
    const e = event.target;
    console.log(`I am button ${e.dataset.id}`);
};
```

```html
<button class='mainButton'>Add Button</button>
```